# XSD; How to mix up complex and simple content?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have multiple XML-files, that can have on the lowest level a HTML `b` or `i` Tag and or text, like the following examples.

```
<root>
  <text>    Hallo Welt, wie geht es so?                             </text>

  <text>    <i>Hallo Welt, wie geht es so?</i>                      </text>
  <text>    Hallo <i>Welt, wie geht es so?</i>                      </text>

  <text>    <b>Hallo Welt, wie geht es so?</b>                      </text>
  <text>    Hallo <b>Welt, wie geht es so?</b>                      </text>

  <text>    <b>Hallo Welt</b>, <i>wie geht es so?</i>               </text>
  <text>    <b>Hallo Welt</b>, <i>wie geht es so</i>?               </text>

  <text>    <i>Hallo Welt</i>, <b>wie geht es so?</b>               </text>
  <text>    <i>Hallo Welt</i>, <b>wie geht es so</b>?               </text>

  <text>    <i>Hallo Welt, <b>wie geht es so</b>?</i>               </text>
  <text>    <b>Hallo Welt, <i>wie geht es so</i>?</b>               </text>

  <text>    Hallo <i>Welt, <b>wie geht es so</b>?</i>               </text>
  <text>    Hallo <b>Welt, <i>wie geht es so</i>?</b>               </text>

  <text>    <b>Hallo <i>Welt</i></b>, <i>wie <b>geht </b></i>es so? </text>
</root>
```

You can mix up `i` with `b` and the other way, you can have just text oder text in just one of the `b` or `i` Tag.

I tried the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="articleType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="author"       type="textType" />
        <xs:element name="title"        type="textType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />      
</xs:complexType>

<!-- TEXT -->
<xs:complexType name="textType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="i"    type="iType"    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="b"    type="bType"    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- I -->
<xs:complexType name="iType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="b"    type="bType"    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- B -->
<xs:complexType name="bType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="i"    type="iType"    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Sadly, this validation site `http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/` tells me the following error:

> Error - Line 7, 50: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 50; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'author' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

Kind Regards

Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Schema provides limited support for mixed content by declaring a `complexType` with [`mixed="true"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#mixedContent), but you can't further constrain the text nodes in mixed content with types.  You can only apply simple types to simple content.